# Shopify retrieving data about a specific product

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I get information about all products in the store using this method and it works: `https: // $ {shop} /admin/api/2021-01/products.json`

Further, through the function, I return data and receive ready-made data about the goods of the store.

But I need to receive information about each specific product

For example: First I want to get information about the first product and this is Yellow Wool Jumper
Then when I want to get information about the second product, then I want to get the Zipped Jacket

Something like this. Found that I can get specific data through these API requests, but it doesn't help at all. I also learned that I can receive information about each specific product through the API. But if there are 100,000 of these products, then it will just be a DDoS attack on the servers, if I make my own request for each product.

So, how can I get data on the first, second and so on products separately, and not so that they are all together?

Comment: Please edit your example. It is hard to understand.  Is there any connection for the products or are they just random products you want to pull?  Some code on what you did will be helpful as wel.

Comment: Why do you need them separately when you can fetch full information of up to 250 products in every request? Serialize your API requests instead of blasting everything in one go.

Comment: I want to get information about each product separately, because I want to load each product into a looped script that will handle each product separately. I found a way to get each product by its id and then use these id to get data about each product in a separate request. But this also turns out to be a heavy load on the Internet traffic and shopify servers.

Comment: However, in any case, I am faced with an additional problem that the contents of variants and images are not displayed to me. Only [Array] and [Object] is displayed in the response, respectively